# iPad stuck in boot up loop. 4013 error after multiple restore attempts

Tags: startup, ipad

After speaking with Apple's tech support, and having them perform a data capture on my machine, I sit stuck with an iPad that won't boot up.  I've attempted all trouble shooting listed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201444). I've updated all iTunes, attempted restore on a Windows 7 machine, two Mac machines, with one iPad power chord, two iPhone power chords, and multiple ports. Every iteration has resulted in the same 4013 error.

Apple concluded it was a hardware issue and would cost $199 to fix. I thought maybe the techies of stackexchange have maybe encountered this issue and had another route to fixing this problem. Thanks for any help you could send.

Answer (score 2):

This may just apply to me, but I resolved this exact situation on my iPhone 5 by:

1. Replacing the screen on my iPhone 5 - I knew it had a faulty screen

It would them boot into the "plug phone into iTunes" screen. Each attempt to resolving using iTunes on Windows 10 resulted in the Error 4013.

2. I updated to OSX 10.11.3 (current version at the time) and the latest iTunes. It restored the phone successfully, and resolved the Error 4013 issue.

Comment: I think for step 2 you are using a macbook instead of the Windows computer, did I understand that correctly?